# git push failing

Tags: git, solaris, version-control

I created centralized git repositories on my department's sun solaris server using

```
mkdir /var/git/myapp.git
cd /var/git/myapp.git
git --bare init
```

last week i did this for 3 of our currently under development applications and pushed the master of these applications to the server

```
git remote add origin ssh://myserver.com/var/git/myapp.git
git push origin master
```

this worked and created the repositories and could clone/pull from them

this week I tried to create a test application and repository so I could test using capistrano to deploy these applications I followed the same precedure

on server:

```
mkdir /var/git/testapp.git
cd /var/git/testapp.git
git --bare init
```

on local:

```
cd /path/to/testapp
git remote add origin ssh://myserver.com/var/git/testapp.git
git push origin master
```

And I got

```
Counting objects: 64, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (56/56), done.
ld.so.1: git: fatal: relocation error: file /usr/local/bin/git: symbole deflateBound: referenced symbol not found
fatal: sha1 file '<stdout>' write error: Invalid argument
error: pack-objects died with strange error
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://myserver.com/var/git/myapp.git'
```

figuring it was an error on my setup I deleted the testapp.git and the testapp on my local machine and started testapp from scratch same result so I tried to push from one of the existing applications and i get the same result even though last week I could push to the server.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd say your git installation in the server is not good.

It's trying to execute /usr/local/bin/git there and some symbol is missing, I'd bet you have a library mismatch.

There is nothing wrong with your repo itself, its the git installation, try executing /usr/local/bin/git manually in the server.

Maybe the git binary you are using in your shell is not /usr/local/bin/git or some failed permissions with required .so libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this with a spotty wireless internet connection between localhost and github; recommend trying with a reliable connection to see if you still have the same issues.